# The Helium mass fraction from the Big Bang Nucleosynthesis

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, big-bang

In Perkin's book Particle Astrophysics (page 144): I do not understand how one comes to the following expression (the second equality with $r$) for the Helium mass fraction due to the Big Bang Nucleosynthesis:

$$Y= \frac{4N_\text{He}}{4N_\text{He}+N_\text{H}}= \frac{2r}{1+r} $$
where $r=N_\text{n}/N_\text{p}$.

The first equality follows from the fact that He is (approximately) 4 times heavier than H:
$$Y = \frac{m_\text{He}}{m_\text{He}+m_\text{H}}= \frac{4N_\text{He}}{4N_\text{He}+N_\text{H}}.$$

However I can't derive the second equality relating $Y$ to $r$:

$N_\text{He}= 2N_\text{p} + 2N_\text{n}$ and  $N_\text{H}= N_\text{p} + N_\text{n}$

$$Y= \frac{4N_\text{He}}{4N_\text{He}+N_\text{H}}= \frac{8(N_\text{n}+N_\text{p})}{9(N_\text{n}+N_\text{p})}\quad???$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have the wrong relations between $\{N_\mathrm{H}, N_\mathrm{He}\}$ and $\{N_\mathrm{p}, N_\mathrm{n}\}$. Every hydrogen contains 1 proton, and every helium contains 2, so $N_\mathrm{p} = N_\mathrm{H} + 2 N_\mathrm{He}$. The neutrons are only contributed to by helium in the accounting: $N_\mathrm{n} = 2 N_\mathrm{He}$. Inverting these relations yields
\begin{align}
N_\mathrm{H} & = N_\mathrm{p} - N_\mathrm{n} \\
N_\mathrm{He} & = \frac{1}{2} N_\mathrm{n}.
\end{align}

It looks like you got the direction wrong, in the sense that there should be *fewer* helium nuclei than protons or neutrons (the 2's are on the wrong side). Also, "hydrogen" means ${}^1\mathrm{H}$ not ${}^2\mathrm{D}$ unless otherwise stated.